# How can I accomplish VPN across Dual Wan connections?

Tags: tcp, vpn, wan, tunnel, site-to-site

How can I accomplish VPN across Dual Wan connections in a optimal way?

[image: plan_for_network_desing_v2]

Idea is to make:

- Site to site VPN.
- **Make single connection inside the VPN to use full bandwidth of both wan connections** using (Split TCP, Multipath TCP, Bonding or technique x?).
- Make it possible for a Road Warrior to have VPN connection to both sites and have traffic use the optimal speed/route.

Note

- The order for "split/bonding" and VPN might not be in optimal/working order in the plan_for_network_desing picture.
- The wan2 and    Road-warriors connections are 4G so they are behind ISP-NAT. So they can "only do" outbound IPv4 connections. Public IPv6-address might be possible.
- The DSL connections have public IPv4 addresses and take incoming connections.

I am interested to know how can I accomplish this?

- What techniques you recommend and how should they be implemented?

Comment: Removed the off-topic recommendation request.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can "load balance" between the DSL and 4G links between the sites simply by adjusting the routing metric so that both paths have equal cost.  The routers will divide connections between the two paths.  Note that a single connection will always use one link, so no single connection can use more than one link's bandwidth.

"Bonding" the links together sounds like a great idea on paper, but in practice it doesn't work very well.  If you try to split a single connection between two links, you will get out of order packets, especially on two different networks,  This will significantly lower your throughput.  You'd be better off using only one link.

VPN software for remote users isn't sophisticated enough to make two VPN connections and then make routing decisions to use the best path.  I'm unaware of any such product.  You would probably have to create something custom, but I doubt it would be worth the effort.

Comment: I have implement solutions in the past using Split TCP and VPN tunnel bonding in layer 2. I managed to get  full throughput on two wan links for a single TCP-session.

Now we also have Multipath TCP (MPTCP), but I don't have experience on it yet.

Solutions I have found so far seems to be 
OpenMPTCProuter and Zeroshell, but would like to hear more expertise on the matter.

Comment: If your paths are the same, then bonding can be a good solution.  But in this case, you have two different links, so the likelihood of out-of-order packets is rather high.

Comment: At any rate, MPTCP is an OS-level feature, so it would be off-topic here.  You could try asking on [sf] for more information.

Comment: Tinc VPN is something that seems to be promising solution related to the Roadwarriors VPN problem, but this another things I would like to hear more expertise on the matter. 

Major problem is to find the final solution that can have all these technologies solutions nicely bundled and supported.

Comment: You will probably find more familiarity with these technologies on [sf].

Comment: For example, this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/850940/how-does-packet-reordering-occur-in-mptcp-and-how-does-it-affect-performance